# Question about classifying the quadratic forms, I got stuck on it

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Q(X) = $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + 2x_3^2 - 2x_1x_3 -2x_2x_3$

$∀x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T ∈ R^3$

Actually, I try to transform this equation to $(x1 - x3)^2 + (x2 - x3)^2$
then I think I should prove it that it is positive definite from my understanding.
For that, I am not sure how to solve this

Comment: The first three terms render $\;Q\;$  **not** a quadratic form. Are you sure you're writing the correct expression?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax Tutorial which will allow you to typeset equations and formulae.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: You’ve rewritten it as the sum of squares of only two linear terms. What does this tell you about its spectrum? What does that, in turn, tell you about definiteness of the quadratic form? Equivalently, can you find nonzero values of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ for which $Q$ vanishes?

Answer (score 1):

$$Q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+2z^2-2xz-2yz$$

Write down the above in matrix form:

$$Q(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&-1\\-1&-1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

and now check the above matrix: is it positive/negative (semi) definite, or none? This will mean your quadratic form is the same (*further hint*: the matrix is singular...)

Yet amd already hinted strongly about the solution to your question, in case you don't want to work with matrices.